# Looping in R like in Stata

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, stata

I'm sure that this is very simple but I cannot find a way to translate this simple loop in Stata to R.

In  the loop is the following

```
forvalues i=1/8{
  gen foo`i'=foo`i'.bar.1+foo`i'.bar.2
}
```

where the `foo's` are numeric vector variables. So, the loop is using `gen` to create eight new variables that are each a sum of two different sets of variables. I'm not sure how to translate that loop into `R`

Comment: Those Stata names are invalid. The `.`s are not allowed.

Comment: What does the loop do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a stata person but it looks like you are creating a set of variables distinguished by numbers in their name by adding two other sets of variables (created elsewhere) that are named the same way.  This is not typically the way we do things in R because it's too easy to create a list of variables and then refer to each variable by its index.  There are tons of options, but one R approach would be something like

```
foo <- list()
for (i in 1:8){
   foo[[i]] <- foo.bar.1[[i]] + foo.bar.2[[i]]
}
```

R actually has innumerable types of data containers, so there could be many others that are better for your application.

But anyway if you really want to include the number in the variable name, you can use the `assign()` and `get()` functions.  Something like

```
for (i in 1:8){
   assign(paste("foo",i,sep=''),get(paste("foo",i,".bar.1",sep=''))+get(paste("foo",i,".bar.2",sep='')))
}
```

Comment: I think you should recommend a solution involves the lefthand-side from your first example and the righthand-side from your second example since it appears the OP wants to dynamically generate the righthand-side variable names in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: ?? Generation of right hand side variable names in the OP involves changing the `i` in the r.h.s., which happens in both of my examples.  Can you clarify your idea?

Comment: When OP writes `foo\`i'.bar.1`, that is equivalent in R to `get(paste("foo",i,".bar.1",sep=''))` (in your second example). I'm just suggesting combining your answers so that it is an exact translation of Stata syntax to R syntax.

Comment: The second example translates the stata work exactly on both sides.  The first example is a preferable way to do it, which does not involve wacky variable names on either side.  We'll let the OP decide, I guess.

Comment: Yes, I suppose this is a question of where the resulting variable is supposed to end up, since in Stata that's only one possible place (back in the original dataset) versus in R it could end up anywhere. You've already got a +1 from me anyway.

Comment: Thanks @farnsy your second solution is what I was aiming at.